# What happens when you configure a Cisco router via SSH and you get disconnected?

Tags: networking, ssh, cisco

**Part 1:**
If I am configuring a router of ssh, and I am connected via the IP of the default route on that router, as soon as I change the default route to another interface / IP, I am thinking the replies will start being routed out that different interface.

Since the replies will have a different src IP, I am guessing that either tcp (see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/61956/tcp-sessions-and-ip-changes)), or ssh is not going to like that, and I will get disconnected.

**Part 2:**
Assuming my logic is right in the first part, what happens if I am configuring via the terminal (config t) and I get disconnected when I switch the default route.

- Will I just be able to connect to the
  IP of the new interface assuming
  there are no ACLs in place?
- I imagine it won't actually resume my
  ssh session, but will all the changes
  I made up to being disconnected still
  be in memory?
- Is there a limit to 1 connection,
  will I have to wait for the timeout?
- Anything else to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to whether your session will be disconnected - it depends.

You say you are connected via the IP of the default route; I take it you mean that you are connect to the IP address of the physical interface which shares a link with the next hop of your default route? e.g. if you have the following configuration:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 ip address 20.20.20.1 255.255.255.0
!

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.10
```

Then you are connected to the route using destination IP address 10.10.10.1?

When you say you are changing the default route, are you changing the next hop of your default route? e.g.:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 20.20.20.20
no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.10
```

(Note, add the new default before removing the old!)

Or, are you changing the interface IP address?

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.10.10.50 255.255.255.0
!
```

In the first case, assuming your workstation is still reachable via 20.20.20.20, your SSH session may hang for a moment or two, but will probably not be disconnected. As you are still connecting to the same IP address, TCP will not disconnect; your packets will simply be routing asymmetrically (going into the router via Fa0/1, and out via Fa0/2).

In the second case, your SSH session will definitely disconnect, as the IP address that is the endpoint of your SSH session will no longer be configured on the router.

If you are disconnected:
* You should be able to connect to the IP address of the new interface, as long as bidirectional routing is in place between your workstation and the new IP address.
* All changes that you have entered will still be in the running configuration; you will need to save them by typing 'copy running-config startup-config'.
* The number of connections will be limited by the number of vty lines you have configured. The default (I believe) is 16; some organisations reduce this for performance/security reasons. Do a 'show run | begin line vty' to see how many lines you have configured.

Without knowing more about your network, it's difficult to suggest improvements; one thing I would say is that if you are running any kind of IGP, then it's probably worth managing your devices using Loopback interfaces. This mitigates against being disconnected while making a change which causes a routing reconvergence.

EDIT: managing via loopback interfaces essentially means ensuring that all of your management traffic (telnet/SSH, syslog, SNMP, TACACS etc) uses the loopback address of your router. This is advantageous for a couple of reasons:

1. When you have a failure which causes reconvergence in your network, existing management sessions aren't interrupted.
2. All management traffic is addressed to a loopback interface, which means that any ACLs/firewall policies restricting management access can be simplified.
3. Re-addressing your network becomes easier, as adding/removing links doesn't change the IP address you use to manage your devices; as long as there is a correctly configured IGP running, you should be able to reach your devices and manage them.

Comment: (Note, add the new default before removing the old!) -- Good point :-).  In this case, I have to interfaces, one which has yet to be configured, and the interface I am connecting to is going to have an Internet IP address.  I know what a loopback interface is, but what do you mean by managing devices using the loopback interfaces?  Do you have a link that shows me how that works?  I am not using IGP currently, but as part of this change, I will be setting up EIGRP.

Comment: Edited with a bit more detail on the use of loopbacks for management. From your comment, it sounds like you will be reconfiguring a device at a remote site? Can you provide a bit more detail on what you will be trying to do? Commissioning a new ISP link to a remote office?

Comment: Doing two of 4 remote offices, then the other two in another day.  Going to be getting a new provider, and replacing the site-to-site VPN tunnels with an MPLS network, and they are providing new internet connections as well.  So the old internet connections will still be hooked up so am going to connect over those.  The reason is that the VPN tunnels will be going over the new internet connections, so I will have to reconfigure them since the IPs will change.  Thankfully, there will be someone near there with latop and aircard, but that will be a bit slow, so that is my backup.

Answer (score 1):

This would be almost the same as changing the address of the interface you are connected to, which I've done a lot of times. My experience is:

- Yes, you will get disconnected.
- Yes, you will be able to connect via the new interface.
- Yes, all changes are still in memory (running-config) as long as the router hasn't been rebooted ("`copy running-config startup-config`" to keep changes between reboots).
- No connection limit timeout (at least I've never encountered one :) ).

Answer (score 1):

I normally would have commented on Terje's answer, but as I'm not "old enough" with serverfault.com to comment, I'll leave an answer.
I'm not as familiar with cisco routers as I am with their ASA's, but I believe all teh command are the same.  I've always used "wr mem" to copy the current config to the memory.  Just a little less to remember :)

Comment: you can skip the 'mem' part too for those of us that are REALLY lazy :) just plain old 'wr' will do the same thing.

Comment: This is a PIX/ASA thing. Normal IOS is always editing running config